# Program returns exception and terminates even though I used "Except - pass"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a webscraper program that scrapes a list of links from a CSV file. The problem is that some of the pages it visits miss part of the information that the program scrapes because the company doesn't provide them. So if the program is scraping phone numbers and emails and then the phone number is missing it returns an exception and terminates. I need it to skip the missing element and NOT terminate the program so it can scrape the rest of the information with the missing information represented as an empty slot in the CSV file.

This is an example webpage that contains all the information and successfully scrapes - [https://reality.idnes.cz/rk/detail/m-m-reality-holding-a-s/5a85b582a26e3a321d4f2700/]

This is an example webpage that is missing both email and number and causes and exception that terminates the program - [https://reality.idnes.cz/rk/detail/narodni-realitni-holding-a-s/5a88aab9e88054474b0eca61/]

I have tried using "try - except(pass)" to fight this so it would skip the exception and continue running the program to my understanding but the program just skips the exception all together and goes to the beginning of the loop and completely skips the information which doesn't get saved to the CSV file.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import csv

with open('links.csv') as read:
    reader = csv.reader(read)
    link_list = list(reader)
    with open('ScrapedContent.csv', 'w+', newline='') as write:
        writer = csv.writer(write)
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        path = "/home/Projects/SRealityContentScraper/chromedriver"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        for link in link_list:
            driver.get(', '.join(link))
            time.sleep(2)
            information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.b-annot__title.mb-5")))
            title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.b-annot__title.mb-5")
            information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.btn__text")))
            offers = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.btn__text")
            information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.font-sm")))
            addresses = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.font-sm")
            try:
                information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.item-icon.measuring-data-layer")))
                phone_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.item-icon.measuring-data-layer")
            except Exception:
                pass
            try:
                information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.item-icon")))
                email = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.item-icon")
            except Exception:
                pass
            print(title.text, " ", offers.text, " ", addresses.text, " ", phone_number.text, " ", email.text)
            writer.writerow([title.text, offers.text, addresses.text, phone_number.text, email.text])

        driver.quit()
```

To my understand "except - continue" should repeat the loop from the beginning and "except - pass" should just ignore the exception and continue running the program normally which doesn't happen. How can I prevent data loss so it would save the information and left out the missing information? Thanks for any help with this I have been trying to figure this out for hours now!

Comment: What's the exception and on which line does it occur? Could it be that your exception is thrown outside your try?

Comment: I can see the last lines in your loop are accessing email.text and phone_number.text even though they won't have been created if the loop failed.... Is that your exception?

Comment: I'll post an answer for you - give me a few mins :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments your problem is that your elements are defined within the try statement.

When the try fails, they are not created and further in the loop you cannot access the `.text`.

As an example, look at this simple code where an object will always fail:

```py
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
try:
    someElement = driver.find_element_by_name('I will Fail!')
except Exception:
    pass
print (someElement.text)
```

This throws this error on the print:

> Exception has occurred: NameError name 'someElement' is not defined

One solution is to create a string variable before the try - set this to blank or whatever default value you want. In the try, set that to text from the element.
If it cannot be found, the try bails and the text value remains as its default.

The code from above becomes this:

```py
someElement_Text = "" # use a string like "" or "none" or "blank" or "not found"
try:
    someElement = driver.find_element_by_name('I will Fail!')
    someElement_Text = someElement.text
except Exception:
    pass
print (someElement_Text)
```

This code does not error.

You'll want to change the latter half of your loop to this:

```
            phone_number_text = ""
            try:
                information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.item-icon.measuring-data-layer")))
                phone_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.item-icon.measuring-data-layer")
                phone_number_text = phone_number.text
            except Exception:
                pass

            email_text = ""
            try:
                information_list = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.item-icon")))
                email = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.item-icon")
                email_text = email.text
            except Exception:
                pass
            print(title.text, " ", offers.text, " ", addresses.text, " ", phone_number_text, " ", email_text)
            writer.writerow([title.text, offers.text, addresses.text, phone_number_text, email_text])
```

Comment: I wanted to write a command explaining how I fixed the issue but Stack Overflow wouldn't let me update it after 5 minutes of posting it...

The suggested steps were the first thing that I tried and it would work but the .text method cannot then work with a string. For this I have created another try loop that assigns email = email.text and if an exception comes email = " " then the writerow and print gets the raw value of email no matter what. Thank you for helping out. The last person didn't post it as a reply so I'm marking this as the solution.